# WoW Addon to REST API

Tags: rest, lua, world-of-warcraft

I´m going to create a web service for learning purposes and wanted to combine it with my WoW Hobby. My goal would be to create a "simple" Addon, which tracks my battleground activity in real time.

So when queuing for AB it enters my data in an db and when I´m out of the BG it should delete the db entry. The information should be stored in an JSON/XML-File and whenever the bg-status changes it should execute the post/update on the DB on the RESTful service.

The real time communication is very important here and I would like to know which ways of communicating to a web service are available, so I could directly dive in and create a solution.I´d like to have resources instead of solutions.

Currently I´m not used to LUA, but would like to learn it to get the knowledge of creating such a service.Which sites are you suggesting for learning LUA, especially the WoW-API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addons only write to disk when you log out of a character (and read that saved data when you log in) so what you intend would not be possible.*

More involved ways of communicating with the rest of the computer or even the internet are prohibited to prevent the gain of certain advantages, an example would be looking up details about your Arena opponents.

<sub>* *Well, there are certainly some ways, but rather complicated ones: a program monitoring sound output to check when the BG queue pop sound is played, or a screengrabber that registers when the BG score screen comes up (which can be viewed during the match though, too)*</sub>

Comment: Thy for the answer, after rethinking it is obvious, that blizzard blocks such real-time communication for prevent such advantages. Would´ve loved to play around with such addon to REST solution =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666990/wow-image-processing ... want to go down the "some ways" road =)

Comment: Kind of funny these days, cuz an addon not allowing internet access is kinda silly.  I can look up details of anything anyways, 3 monitors...  Shoot I can dual box 3 accounts at the same time.

Comment: The issue of security remains. An addon with internet access could download new code that cannot be reviewed before being executed. And public awareness of the risks of addons & custom code is higher than ever, after some people tricked others into executing a one-liner that replaced the "write text to chat window" function with one that executes code, so they could remote-control other people's API functions, e.g. trading all gold - without the victims even noticing immediately.